# Select multiple images from custom field

Tags: custom-field, images, uploads

I've created a custom field with image select/upload. This only makes me select one image, but I want to be able to select multiple images.

Been looking for this quite some time but still not managed to get it to work.

The code I use is:

```
 <p>
    <label for="projects[image]">Image Upload</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="projects[image]" id="projects[image]" class="meta-image regular-text" value="<?php echo $meta['image']; ?>">
    <input type="button" class="button image-upload" value="Browse">
</p>
<div class="image-preview"><img src="<?php echo $meta['image']; ?>" style="max-width: 250px;"></div>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        // Instantiates the variable that holds the media library frame.
        var meta_image_frame
        // Runs when the image button is clicked.
        $('.image-upload').click(function (e) {
        // Get preview pane
        var meta_image_preview = $(this).parent().parent().children('.image-preview')
        // Prevents the default action from occuring.
        e.preventDefault()
        var meta_image = $(this).parent().children('.meta-image')
        // If the frame already exists, re-open it.
        if (meta_image_frame) {
            meta_image_frame.open()
            return
        }
        // Sets up the media library frame
        meta_image_frame = wp.media.frames.meta_image_frame = wp.media({
            title: meta_image.title,
            button: {
            text: meta_image.button,
            },
        })
        // Runs when an image is selected.
        meta_image_frame.on('select', function () {
            // Grabs the attachment selection and creates a JSON representation of the model.
            var media_attachment = meta_image_frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON()
            // Sends the attachment URL to our custom image input field.
            meta_image.val(media_attachment.url)
            meta_image_preview.children('img').attr('src', media_attachment.url)
        })
        // Opens the media library frame.
        meta_image_frame.open()
        })
    })
</script>
```

Hope somebody can give me some help :).

Thanks in advance,
Koen

Answer (score -1):

Maybe someone else has this issue, I found this!
https://wordpress.org/plugins/navz-photo-gallery/

Comment: Any reason for a minus vote, man?